# Problem/bug with Beamer and multimedia package

Tags: beamer, multimedia, bugs

EDIT: This is indeed a bug that has been fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/437#event-1377360577 and should be available soon.

Since updating Miktex today (12/7/2017) I cannot compile my slides anymore. I keep getting the error

> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\multimedia\multimedia.sty"
>   ! Undefined control sequence.
>    \beamer@pdfobj
>                             stream attr {/R 22050} {}\beamer@pdfrefobj \beamer...
>   l.262 }

Deleting the multimedia package resolves the error. This seems like a bug as the beamer manual explicitly states that the package is compatible. I do not know where else to post this. A MWE is:

```
\documentclass[beamer,usepdftitle=false]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
\title[]{\textbf{MWE}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: it works fine at me (compiled with xelatex). do you have installed recent and all needed packages?

Comment: see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/437#event-1377360577

Comment: @samcarter Thanks a lot. When googling for beamer and bugs, I somehow missed the Github page. That explains it.

Comment: Fix is on it's way to CTAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in beamer version `3.45`, see the bug report in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/437

It was fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/7ea0bc4235dc3a310e82e7408d5e57f80ce4e739

Temporary workaround: place https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/7ea0bc4235dc3a310e82e7408d5e57f80ce4e739/base/multimedia/multimedia.sty in your working directory