# Puzzled about embedding sound in a beamer slide

Tags: beamer, embedding, multimedia

I am puzzled with how to embed a sound file in a beamer slide. For instance I try:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\sound[autostart]{sound poster text}{sound_file}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `sound_file` is in the same folder with the .tex file. But there isn't any sound in the pdf file. Is this the proper way?

Comment: Ensure you are up to date not using an old buggy versions such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405082/170109   However although it may eventually work ask yourself a few questions 1) who else would ever want to run your documents on their machines as they should now flag as an executable.PDF risk? hence fewer and fewer can be run by acrobat 2) If its only for your use on your hardware how to keep it simple since flash dies soon. Consider future simple media formats such as html5 based., You need to confirm what type of media you are loading as it should only be standard .mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had several problems finding a simple \sound file that would work across viewers and got some success with your mwe code producing garbled sounds in acrobat but foxit reader was even worse (normally the most similar to acrobat) In the end I took another approach and downloaded an example that does work well using several other methods so suggest you look at this sample https://www2.le.ac.uk/departments/mathematics/extranet/staff-material/resource-downloads/beamer-presentation and others on this site https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbeamer%5D+sound