# playing mp4 file inside beamer

Tags: beamer, multimedia

I have an mp4 file I would like to use in my beamer presentation.

My MWE is below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Sound example}
     \movie[width=8cm,height=4.5cm]{test}{151351913876539.mp4}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am using LyX2.3 in a windows 10 environment.
My problem is that while the latex file compiles and delivers a pdf output;
when I click on the link, I get the following message.

[image]

Comment: The message is usually correct if the file exists in the same folder as the pdf it will A) warn about opening untrusted files OR B) state it is an unsupported type C)possibly ask if you want to open an alternative file D) tell you the file does not exist if the name does not match SO my 1st question is why is it trying to open a temporary folder is that where the pdf is ?

Comment: That is also my question.

Comment: OK since you did not wilfully put it there it is a quirk of Lyx to build the tex and pdf files in a temporary folder but it does not transport the external mp4, you need LyX to somehow save the pdf in the folder that has the mp4.file (possibly easier said than done) I suggest this is one for lyx support or else save the tex local with mp4 and run `pdfLaTeX mp4test.tex`  from command line in the mp4 folder P.S there are command for some media packages that can embed the media

Comment: Pkg `multimedia` implements an old part of the PDF specification that allows playback of AVI and MOV files only. For MP4/h264 encoded videos you need the so-called RichMedia annotation, provided by pkg `media9`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345431

Comment: @AlexG Agreed that it may not work with such a file or even other type/formats, however the message would be something like ...mp4 is not a supported file type. Would you like to choose a replacement file? with a yes no option. What happens with LyX is different even if the sound format is an acceptable one.

Comment: I used media9 package (it supports different rich files) instead of multimedia. I also updated the l3 latex packages and it works. Now, I will try to get my sound file to work.

Comment: for sound with wav etc see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483539/puzzled-about-embedding-sound-in-a-beamer-slide/483610?r=SearchResults&s=3|0.0000#483610